# Alternate ways to add 2 lines to a file too large for me to open

Tags: regex, perl, sed, large-files

I have a JSON file that is too large for Notepad++ to open. I was told WordPad would open it, but it just hung.

The file needs to have an open bracket `[` on a new line at the beginning of the file, and a close bracket `]` on a new line at the end of the file.

I already used `sed` to put commas at the end of each line in this file, using a command I found here. But, I don't know enough about `sed` and regex to write my own for the brackets, and I don't want to mess it up.

I also found this Perl command for adding two lines at the beginning of a file:

```
perl -pi -e '$.=0 if eof;print "first line\nsecond line\n" if ($.==1)' *.txt
```

I don't understand what it is saying. Could it be adjusted for 1 at the beginning and 1 at the end? If you can explain it, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Manually cobbling together JSON maybe hazardous to your process.

Comment: [TextPad](http://www.textpad.com/products/textpad/summary.html) is a nice text editor for Windows that supports huge files and includes a one-month trial period. Before I paid for my copy it was just issuing warnings every so often and never actually stopped you using it.

Comment: How could it be hazardous, Sinan Unur? I am just adding brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With sed:

```
sed -i -e '1i[' -e '$a]' filename
```

That is

```
1 i [   # before the first line, insert a line "["
$ a ]   # after the last line, append a line "]"
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have enough space on your disk to stand two files of the same size, you can use a simple bash script:

```
echo "[" > corrected-file.txt
cat original-file.txt >> corrected-file.txt
echo "]" >> corrected-file.txt
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you make a new file with just an open bracket, you concatenate that file to the front of my big file, then does that last line add the bracket to the end of the new file. I wonder, would it be easier for me to make two new files, one with my start line and one with my end line, and can I then cat them with my big file?

Comment: @punstress, no - the solution **1.)** the `echo` **create**  the `corrected-file.txt` with a content `[`. **2.)** the `cat` **appends** the `original-file.txt` to the `corrected-file.txt`, and **3.)** the final echo again **appends** the final `]`. Nice, easy solution without any voodoo.. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Create two files in notepad, one with only `[` in it, name it `beginning` , another with `]` in it, name it `end`. Then use `cat`.

```
cat beginning yourawfullybigfile end > yournewfilewithbothbracketsinit
```

you may as well use free emeditor, and edit your big file as you would in notepad++ if it was small enough

Comment: I just looked at emeditor; apparently the free version doesn't include large files. Maybe it would during the trial period but, alas, it won't install on Win XP. Oh well.

Answer (score 2):

`$.=0 if eof`

This resets the line counter `$.` if several files are processed at once.

`print "first line\nsecond line\n" if $. == 1`

If the counter is set to 1, i.e. the script is reading the first line, output the two lines you want to prepend.

So, adjusting it to prepend `[` and append `]` would be

```
perl -i~ -pe '$. = 0, $_ .= /\n/ ? "]\n" : "\n]\n" if eof; print "[\n" if 1 == $.;' *.txt
```

Explanation:

`$_ .= /\n/ ? "]\n" : "\n]\n" if eof`

At the end of the file, we want to add `]`. But, the file could have ended with a newline, or without it. If there was the newline, we just add the `]\n`, if there wasn't, we need to add it, too.

Answer (score 0):

You are on Windows. Follow [joe's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29194419/100754), and create two files. Then use `copy`

```
C:\> copy /b beginning + yourfile + end newfile
```

Comment: I've been using bash, not Windows command line. So I can use cat and echo.